# Bittwiste unexpected behaviour when changing MAC address

Tags: packet-analysis, pcap

`bittwiste version 2.0 libpcap version 1.9.1 on Catalina vía Homebrew`

I have a pcap file `foo.pcap` with conversation between MAC addresses `a2:f6:51:d0:0e:13` and   `ac:93:c4:be:6b:8c`

I run:

```
bittwiste -I foo.pcap -O bar.pcap -T eth -s a2:f6:51:d0:0e:13,a2:f6:51:d0:0e:ff

input file: foo.pcap
output file: bar.pcap
```

Open `bar.pcap` on Wireshark and the source MAC addresses haven't changed. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to manipulate an Ethernet header, when really you've got an 802.11 frame which is not at all the same. An 802.11 frame doesn't only carry source and destination addresses but also transmitter and receiver addresses, and its header structure is quite different.

It's likely that bittwiste is unable to manipulate Wi-fi headers at all, judging from the [man page](https://manpages.org/bittwiste):

> Bittwiste is designed to work only with Ethernet frame

.